# Closing jQuery colorbox on keyup ESC

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using  [Jquery colorbbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)

I am trying to close colorbox  While keyup the ESC button from the keyboard

I am using the following code

```
<script>
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    // ESCAPE key pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $.colorbox.close()
      //  window.close();

    }
});

</script>
```

After loading the colorbox Js and css file unfortunately it is not working for me.

Comment: Could you provide with jsfiddle demo?

Comment: In the ColorBox settings list there is an option: `escKey` which stands for: *If false, will disable closing colorbox on 'esc' key press*. It should make the job for you. Have you tried to set `true` for it?

Comment: no Where to set  that in colorbox.js   file ?

Comment: Yeah got it thanks  Vision if you want to give answer then ok otherwise i will delete the question

Answer (score 1):

Based on [VisioN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249581/vision) comment. Here is what you need to do I guess

```
$("a.gallery").colorbox({escKey:true});
```

Comment: I am hoping it will not effect the other colorboxes on same page

Comment: It won't.  That will only apply to the "a.gallery" elements.